# regex replacement - number between nodes

Tags: php, regex

This is my regex:

`\^((<i><b>|<b><i>)(\d+)(\<\/b>\<\/i>|\<\/i>\<\/b>))?\s+/mi`

It is supposed to catch `<i><b>14</b></i>  some text`

The good news is that it catches `<i><b>14</b></i>` as `\1` which is what I need for step 1 of the function.

The bad news is that I can't figure out how to write the replacement variable to catch `14` and replace it with number `1`

What I tried was `\21\4`, where `\2` stood for `<i><b>` and `\4` stood for `</b></i>` but the whole thing gets interpreted as `\21` not `\2`. I can't have the space after `\2`

What's the right way to write the replacement variable?

Comment: Writing yet another XML parser using regex?

Comment: that would be way above my skills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookaround based regex:

```
$re = '~(?:<[bi]>)*\b(\d+)\b(?:</[bi]>)*~m';
$str = preg_replace($re, '$0 :: $1', '<i><b>14</b></i>');
//=> <i><b>14</b></i> :: 14
```

Though it will be safer to parse your HTML using DOM parser and and then manipulate it.

Comment: I need to preserve the ability to replace the entire <i><b>14</b></i> as \1

Comment: So output should should just be `1` ?

Comment: The same $re when used with two different replacement variables should  catch <i><b>14</b></i> in the first case and 14 in the second case.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly: In order to disambiguate backreference `$2` and the number `1` from backreference `$21`, you can use braces:

```
${2}1
```